# Does String.Split method ensure order in result array?

Tags: c#, .net, string, split

Fluent googling doesn't give an answer, so question is:

Does `String.Split` method ensure order of resulted substrings in according to they position in initial string?

Comment: You got a good answer, and probably the best we can expect. I have to point out, though, that just because the current implementation puts things in the expected order, that's not really a guarantee. That said, it would be idiotic for the BCL team to change the order. It just wouldn't make any sense.

Comment: Thanks for useful comment Jim. No matter that changing the order in String.Split is unlikely, probably it's better to avoid expecting consistent order from split method.

Comment: On the contrary. I would expect consistent order from the split method. If I couldn't depend on the order, `String.Split` would be almost useless. I think it's not explicitly stated because nobody thought of pointing out something so "obvious." I think they should document the behavior.

Comment: @JimMischel: Given that some programmers feel free to eke out "performance optimizations" by changing any behaviors that aren't documented, without regard for whether any code might rely upon those behaviors, I concur that documenting even "obvious" behaviors that programmers are entitled to take advantage of can be a good idea.  If the Framework had a "substring" object type which behaved like `String` but held a reference to another `String` along with a starting offset and length (a design which could improve performance *if treated specially by the GC), then it might make sense...

Comment: ...to have a split with multiple separator types work by splitting the main string on one separator type, and then subdivide the resulting strings using other separators.  An implementation that was free to return strings in arbitrary order could potentially be a tiny bit faster than one which had to return them in source-string order, so in theory, in the absence of documentation to the contrary, a crazy programmer implementing the split might use such an implementation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to what [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ilspy.ashx) shows on the internals of `string.Split`, the answer is **yes**.

```
private string[] InternalSplitKeepEmptyEntries(
    int[] sepList, int[] lengthList, int numReplaces, int count)
{
    int num = 0;
    int num2 = 0;
    count--;
    int num3 = (numReplaces < count) ? numReplaces : count;
    string[] array = new string[num3 + 1];
    int num4 = 0;
    while (num4 < num3 && num < this.Length)
    {
        array[num2++] = this.Substring(num, sepList[num4] - num);
        num = sepList[num4] + ((lengthList == null) ? 1 : lengthList[num4]);
        num4++;
    }
    if (num < this.Length && num3 >= 0)
    {
        array[num2] = this.Substring(num);
    }
    else
    {
        if (num2 == num3)
        {
            array[num2] = string.Empty;
        }
    }
    return array;
}
```

All elements (e.g. the `array` variable) are always processed in ascending order and no sorting occurs.

The [MSDN documentation for `string.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) also lists examples which have results in the same order as their order in the original string.

As [Jim Mischel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/56778/jim-mischel) points out above, this is only the *current* implementation, which might change.

Comment: Solid proof. And nice speed too.

Answer (score 2):

Yes is does. Otherwise it would be rather useless.